# RX Java 2 how to track total processing time of each event?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have the below code and I would like track how much time the HttpRequest took and log it.

In sequential code we usually stamp the start, execute and stamp the end and finally ***(endTime - startTime)***.

It should be able to print the time taken on success or failure.

```
io.reactivex.Flowable
    .fromIterable(records.records())
    .parallel(5)
    .flatMap(record -> {
                Single<HttpResponse<String>> request = client
                        .get(xxxxxx, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" , "/xxxxxxx")
                        .as(BodyCodec.string())
                        .rxSend();

                return request.toFlowable();
            }
    )
    .sequential()
    .subscribe(record -> {
        System.out.println(record.body());
    }, ex -> {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    });
```

I managed to pull it off like this. But it doesn't cover Exceptions, is this the right direction?

```
io.reactivex.Flowable
    .fromIterable(records.records())
    .parallel(5)
    .flatMap(record -> {
        Single<HttpResponse<String>> request = client
                .get(xxxxxx, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" , "xxxxxx")
                .as(BodyCodec.string())
                .rxSend();

        MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(System.currentTimeMillis(), request);

        return Flowable.just(wrapper);
            }
    )
    .sequential()
    .subscribe(record -> {
        long startTime = record.getStartTime();

        record.getHttpResponse().toFlowable().subscribe(t -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Took: " + (endTime - startTime) + " - " + t.body());
                });


    }, ex -> {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a `timestamp()` operator that you can add to your chain. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Yeah but it can only be added after the sequential and taking time difference with time stamp and the time inside the subscribe results to 0ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick quite well...

```
.flatMap(record -> {
        Single<HttpResponse<String>> request = client
                .get(xxxxxx, "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx")
                .as(BodyCodec.string())
                .rxSend();

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return request.toFlowable()
                .doOnError(ex -> {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    System.out.println("Took: " + (endTime - startTime));

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                })
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    System.out.println("Took: " + (endTime - startTime));
                });
    }
)
```